# How to navigate to the next page after completing the animation?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I am trying to do an animation for the Splashscreen in windows phone 8. I've completed the animation for an object to bounce. But after completing the animation it should immediately switch to the next page. How to do this task?

```
    //MainPage.xaml
        <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="arc">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-555">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="-150"/>

                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <es:Arc x:Name="arc" ArcThickness="20" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="174,369.5,0,0" Stretch="None" Stroke="Black" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Loaded="arc_Loaded">
                <es:Arc.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform/>
                </es:Arc.RenderTransform>
                <es:Arc.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3B9E5B" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8D2727" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </es:Arc.Fill>
            </es:Arc>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: Why did you ad wpf tag to your question?

Comment: xaml supported by wpf. so i added.

Comment: No, WPF is not a XAML. On Windows Phone there is a subset of Silverlight, but not a WPF. So that means that sometimes you will be unable to compile WPF code on Windows Phone. Do you really need useles answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres the solution to it But I guess you need to share more about the problem if this doesnot help

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardTest" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
                //What ever animation you want to do
            </Storyboard>
```

And in the cs file:

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

For a demo on animating splash screen go to this link
[progress bar splash screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx) and apply your animation accordingly.

Comment: my animation is for 5 sec. Only after completion of the animation it should navigate to the next screen. I don't need just the navigation.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more I guess I can come up with a solution. If you have any code piece then please share :)

Comment: the above animation is bouncing effect. it is linked to an object called "arc". So, for 5 sec this object bounces on the screen. And immediately after this animation completed the page should navigate to the next screen. that's all. thank u.

Comment: I guess then the navigation service will take care of the navigation to next screen :)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the Storyboard's `Completed` event.

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard;

if(myStoryboard != null)
{
    myStoryboard.Completed += (s,e) => 
           {
             NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NextPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
           };
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: i am sorry. this is not working. after completion of the 5 sec above animation it should navigate itself to the next page.

Comment: Can you show your how you're calling the animation? The `Completed` event should fire after the animation has finished.

Comment: pls check modified code now. called in xaml file itself named "arc".

Comment: Where do you call `Begin` on your Storyboard?

Comment: entire animation done in xaml.  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-555"> is the beginning point at 0 sec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37336/discussion-between-madhu-kumar-and-keyboardp)

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the next page in Completed event of the sotryboard.

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" Completed="Storyboard_Completed_1">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="arc">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-555">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="-150"/>

                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void Storyboard_Completed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you wanted
}
```